# Is it possible to write a custom GraphQL resolver for Craft?

Tags: graphql

I am currently editing a headless VueJS + Craft + GraphQL website and the client asks me to add a Recipe section. I found https://plugins.craftcms.com/recipe which is great, but when I add the field to my section and I write my GraphQL query, it doesn't seem to be able to resolve the field type of Recipe.

Here's what I get in "debugMessage" from the GraphQL api.

`Expected a value of type \"String\" but received: instance of nystudio107\\recipe\\models\\Recipe`

Now, if I understand right, the problem either that I'm not specifying the type correctly when I query my content or that I would need to write a custom resolver to "unpack" the plugin's class into scalar types. So that brings me to the question: is it possible to hook into Craft's resolving mecanism and unpack custom fields?

I also am already using the elements api for some other endpoints and that might be what I end up doing to solve the problem, but I'd love to stay in GraphQL for consistency if possible.

Thank you everyone for your time!

--

For reference, here's my query and the "recetteContenu" field is the recipe field.

```javascript
let query = `
  query FetchEntries($lang: [String], $slug: [String]) {
    entry (section: "recette", site: $lang, slug: $slug) {
      title,
      ... on recette_recette_Entry {
        category: recetteCategory { id, ... on recettes_Category { title } },
        recetteContenu
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Sorry, sadly no. Since I was working on a schedule, I had to resolve myself working with the elements API for that part sadly. I'd love to learn how to do it though and I have 100+ hours to put into that same project later this year so if I can learn how before then, I could refactor my code at that moment.

Comment: @Eric Just as a follow up, I reached out to Craft's support and they told me that I had great timing because they created new documentation pages recently outlining how to do exactly this. I'll put the links in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

So after reaching out to Craft's support, they very kindly pointed out that I had great timing because they had just launched new documentation pages outlining details on how to create GraphQL resolvers.

Documentation about the required Interfaces:
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/graphql.html#interfaces

Documentation on the folder structure of such a system and the events emitted by GraphQL to allow modifying simple queries before they're sent back to the client:
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/graphql.html#interfaces

Even though I answered to my own question over time, I think this should be the approved answer since this is official documentation in the end.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for looking into this and linking!

Comment: You may find this of use:

https://github.com/lsst-epo/craft3-nested-entries-graphql-queries

It's a graphQL Craft plugin I created with the help of the Craft community, maybe it fits your use case - if anything it's an example of functioning code with not a custom resolver, but custom query.